# Why does neither topproc nor multicpu work correctly in xmobar?

Tags: xmonad

I get the error "could not execute command topproc" and "autototal% not found" when using the topproc and multicpu commands below. I believe the syntax is correct ( does not work either). What am I doing wrong? This is xmobar 0.13-2 from Ubuntu precise

```
-- http://projects.haskell.org/xmobar/#system-monitor-plugins

Config {
       font = "xft:Monospace:pixelsize=11",
       -- used to make the bar appear correctly after Mod-q in older xmonad implementations (0.9.x)
       -- doesn't seem to do anything anymore (0.10, darcs)
--       lowerOnStart = False,
       commands = [
                Run TopProc [] 20,
                Run TopMem [] 20,
                -- Run ThermalZone ["-t","<id>: <temp>C"] 30
                -- Run DiskIO Disks [("/", "<read> <write>"), ("sdb1", "<total>")] [] 10
                -- CoreTemp
                Run Weather "KSFO" ["-t"," <tempC>C","-L","-20","-H","30","--normal","green","--high","red","--low","lightblue"] 36000,
                Run MultiCpu ["-t", "<autototal%>%", "-L","3","-H","50","--normal","green","--high","red"] 10,
                Run Memory ["-t","Mem: <usedratio>%"] 10,
                Run Swap [] 10,
                Run Date "%a %b %_d %l:%M" "date" 10,
                Run Network "eth0" [] 10,
                Run StdinReader
                ]
       , sepChar = "%"
       , alignSep = "}{"
       , template = "%StdinReader% }{ %topproc% | %topmem% | %eth0% | %multicpu% | %memory% * %swap%    <fc=#ee9a00>%date%</fc> | %KSFO%"
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%topproc% needs to be changed to %top%. I don't know why autototal doesn't work but I settled for "total".

Answer (score 3):

its just a typo, remove the %

```
 Run MultiCpu ["-t", "<autototal>%", "-L","3","-H","50","--normal","green","--high","red"] 10,
```